# Mixin class to trace attribute requests - __attribute__ recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to create a class which must be superclass of others, tracing their attribute requests. I thought of using "**getattribute**" which gets all attribute requests, but it generates recursion:

```
class Mixin(object):
 def __getattribute__ (self, attr):
  print self, "getting", attr
         return self.__dict__[attr]
```

I know why I get recursion: it's for the self.**dict** call which recalls **getattribute** recursively. I've tryied to change last line in `"return object.__getattribute__(self,attr)"` like suggested in other posts but recursion is recalled.

Comment: Using `return object.__getattribute__(self,attr)` works for me.  Can you give a fuller example of when you get recursion using this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Mixin(object):
    def __getattribute__ (self, attr):
        print self, "getting", attr
        return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

If you are still getting recursion problems, it is caused by code you haven't shown us

```
>>> class Mixin(object):
...     def __getattribute__ (self, attr):
...         print self, "getting", attr
...         return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
...
>>> Mixin().__str__
<__main__.Mixin object at 0x00B47870> getting __str__
<method-wrapper '__str__' of Mixin object at 0x00B47870>
>>> Mixin().foobar
<__main__.Mixin object at 0x00B47670> getting foobar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __getattribute__
AttributeError: 'Mixin' object has no attribute 'foobar'
>>>
```

And here is the result when combined with Bob's `Mylist`

```
>>> class Mylist(Mixin):
...     def __init__ (self, lista):
...         if not type (lista) == type (""):
...             self.value = lista[:]
...     def __add__ (self,some):
...         return self.value + some
...     def __getitem__ (self,item):
...         return self.value[item]
...     def __getslice__ (self, beg, end):
...         return self.value[beg:end]
...
>>> a=Mylist([1,2])
>>> a.value
<__main__.Mylist object at 0x00B47A90> getting value
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Um... "I've tryied to change last line in `return object.__getattribute__(self,attr)` like suggested in other posts but recursion is recalled." -- OP

Comment: @delnan, Bob_Bib, the code I posted is correct. If you are still seeing recursion, please post all the code you are using and the traceback

Comment: since someone was so lazy to downvote this answer without even trying it, I've added some sample output from the console

Comment: Okay, obviously the flaw is in Bob_Bib's code - undownvote + upvote + apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```
from Es123 import Mixin
class Mylist(Mixin):
    def __init__ (self, lista):
        if not type (lista) == type (""):
            self.value = lista[:]
    def __add__ (self,some):
        return self.value + some
    def __getitem__ (self,item):
        return self.value[item]
    def __getslice__ (self, beg, end):
        return self.value[beg:end]
a = Mylist ([1,2])
a.value
```

Then python returns "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Comment: That should work fine with the Mixin class from my answer. Check that `Es123.py` has the correct version of the class. If it still doesn't work, post the whole traceback

Comment: Yes, it works! Sorry I left the wrong version so it didn't work. Thank you. Could you explain to me why it works with object.__getattribute__(...) but not with only __getattribute__(...) please?

Comment: `self.__getattribute__` calls `Mixin`'s `__getattribute__` method, which calls itself recursively. `object.__getattribute__` calls `object`'s `__getattribute__` method which is wholey different than `Mixin`'s method of the same name. Hence, no recursion.